# How to res.render a view and remove parameters from URL in address bar while still passing data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

To render the view I currently have:

```js
statVars["sessions"] = userSessions;
res.render("statsSessions", statVars);
```

However, I need to prevent the URL parameters from appearing in the address bar (they come from the form submit on the previous page), but I need to retain the data in statVars object I'm passing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
```

Its difficult to answer based on amount of information you have shared.
But i would suggest use method="post" for form submission to prevent the URL parameters from appearing in the address bar